# SVN: file renamed, I only know the *old* name, how can I find the *current* name of this file?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

So I have a file that was renamed a couple of years ago before I joined the project. I know the old name but the file isn't there in a fresh checkout of the current version, and I can't find what the current file's name is.

I have tried: `svn log --verbose` in Linux, redirected output to a text file, used the search feature a text editor to find the filename in the history. It is there, but if it disappears because it was renamed, I would expect the last occurrence of this name to be the commit that deleted it or renamed it. Actually, no, the last time the file shows up it was *modified*, not deleted nor renamed. Also tried looking at the log in tortoise in Windows and filtering by the file's name, same result.

(I say "deleted or renamed" because I'm not excluding the possibility that the renaming wasn't correctly recorded, so it might show up as deleted and readded, but in this case I would expect the deletion commit to be there).

Any other method to find this misterious new name? Also, what if the renaming had taken place in a branch that was later merged into the trunk, would it still show up in the revision in which the merge was committed?

Comment: `svn log -r 1:HEAD $FILENAME $ROOT-OF-REPO` and `svn log -v $MAX_REV` after you'll find latest changeset in which filename was referenced by first log

Comment: There's a good chance that whoever renamed it, didn't do an svn mv. and instead did a `remove` and `add` and called it a day. I would just check the file history of that file to when it was first added to the repository and check the changeset of the commit in which it was added (which is what Lazy Badger is suggesting). If you're using TortoiseSVN, just right click on the file and check the history of that file.

Comment: @LazyBadger I think you might have to swap the order of filename and root, make filename relative, and use "@" to specify a revision in which the file still existed because otherwise svn log displays an error saying it cannot find it. But with these few changes your solution works, thanks.

Comment: @Chris that works too, just adding for future googlers that you have to checkout an old revision in which the file still existed. And yes I was considering the possibility that it was deleted and readded instead of renamed... in the end using your method I discovered the *directory* was deleted, not the file itself, which might explain why the commit didn't show up when looking at the file's history. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ansering my own question in case someone finds it in google. How I finally solved it: instead of looking at the history of the misterious file, looked at *other* files that had references to it, i.e. usages of that class. Then I could see what the new name of the class is. This was easy in Java because every public class is required to be place in a file with the same name; you might not be that lucky e.g. in C++, but you can still look at the new name of a class (or the same name if it hasn't changed) and see what file it is now declared in. Hope this helps someone facing the same problem in the future.